# Losing TextInput's focus when Keyboard closes

Tags: react-native

I have some `TextInput` components inside a `ScrollView`. The problem si that if I am closing the keyboard with return or android back button, the `TextInput` selected is still focused and I have to tap two times to focus another `TextInput`.

Here are the components I am using:

```
<ScrollView style = {styles.scroll}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView styles={styles.container} behavior = 'padding'  enabled>
                    <View style={styles.header1}><Text style={styles.title}>Blue Line Notes</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.headerDesign}></View>
                    <View style={styles.header2}></View>

                    <View style = {styles.items}>
                        <TextInput
                            style = {styles.subject} 
                            onChangeText={(noteTitle)=> this.setState({noteTitle})} 
                            value={this.state.noteTitle}
                            placeholder='Raport Number/Note Indentifier'
                            placeholderTextColor='grey'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style = {styles.items}>
                        <TextInput
                            style = {styles.calltype} 
                            multiline = {true}
                            numberOfLines = {3}
                            onChangeText={(callType)=> this.setState({callType})} 
                            value={this.state.callType}
                            placeholder='Call Type/Other Information'
                            placeholderTextColor='grey'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style = {styles.items}>
                        <TextInput 
                            multiline = {true}
                            numberOfLines = {8}
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            placeholder='Notes'
                            onChangeText={(noteText)=> this.setState({noteText})}
                            value={this.state.noteText}
                            placeholderTextColor='grey'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>


                        <View style = {styles.items}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress = { this.saveNote.bind(this)} style={styles.addButton}>
                                <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>SAVE</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScrollView>
```

What I think I need to do is to lose the focus of the `TextInput` when the keyboard closes. That is something I am struggling with. Can someone show me how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"` as `ScrollView` attribute. I tried the same on your given code and it worked. You can look more into the property details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps).

Hope this will help!

Comment: Sound too easy. In my experience I am alergic to easy. We shall see :)